# How to create a new user on Dynamics CRM Online through calling APIs

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, office365, dynamics-crm-2013

I want to design an application to sync user information between local system and CRM online. I found we can't create user in CRM online through APIs directly as CRM on-premise. System said we only can add user through office 365 admin portal. But I have no idea about how to use office 365 APIs to create CRM online user. Did you guys encounter the situation before? Please help me, thanks!

Comment: what error messages do you get when calling the create service on a system user?  I haven't tried online myself, but the MS consultants have told us that when using the 2013 APIs, online and on-premise are equivalent.  We also create system users through the APIs and that would be an issue for us if we move to the cloud.

Comment: nevermind my last question.  I poked around in our online sandbox and found the messages you're referring to.  It looks like MS wants you to use their Office 365 Single Sign On and AD Synchronization features to  set up your local users as CRM Online users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, let me answer my question. Right now if we want to operate Dynamics CRM Online User or License information, we need to operate Active Directory Graph Service associated with CRM Online. This Service is a web api based service. We can get the example code on "http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7e947621-ef93-4de7-93d3-d796c43ba34f", and current there is one helper library can be used you guys can download it on http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Windows-Azure-AD-Graph-API-a8c72e18.